# Need help on "advance" csv table import

Tags: tables, csv, excel

I am trying to import a .csv table that has new line characters on select cells. [image].

The .csv code looks like this:

```
title 1,title 2,title 3
item 1,"data 1a
data 1b","result 1a
result 1b"
item 2,data 2,result 2
item 3,data 3,"result 3a
result 3b"
```

[image]

I understand that .csv identifies 2-row cell using quotation marks and moving data to the new line, but this does not work well with my latex \csvreader. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You may add a feature request for `csvsimple` here: https://github.com/T-F-S/csvsimple/issues